# Some first name fields have a middle initial and some don't, how do I remove the initial in MSSQL

Tags: string, character, trim, string-length

I need to concatenate the columns LastName and FirstName into a new column called EmployeeName. The problem is that some first name fields include a middle initial and some do not. We do not want the initial in the EmployeeName column. How do I remove it from those instances?

I have tried trim functions, left functions, right functions and I cannot get it to work quite right. I have tried concatenating the columns then cleaning it up, that does not work either

SELECT LEFT(EmployeeName, LEN(EmployeeName) - 2) FROM myTable
but this removes the last characters even for those with no middle initial. I have it as -2 to account for the space between FirstName and Middle Initial

When the EmployeeName field is Smith, John J it removes the space and J correctly

When the EmployeeName field is Smith, John it removes the 'hn'. I don't want that.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I count the spaces then use a case statement to concatenate the fields

select LastName, FirstName, 
( 
 case
 when len(firstname) - len(replace(firstname, ' ', '')) > 0
 then concat(LEFT(firstname, LEN(firstname) - 2),', ',LastName)
 ELSE concat(FirstName, ', ', Lastname)
 END
 ) as namesCombined
from myTable